# PHP Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found with PHPUnit 6 and PHP 7.0

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, php-7

I am playing with php 7 and phpunit 6. Here is the test I wrote:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test;

use DesignPatterns\Observer\User;
use DesignPatterns\Observer\UserObserver;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ObserverTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testChangeInUserLeadsToUserObserverBeingNotified()
    {
        $observer = new UserObserver();

        $user = new User();
        $user->attach($observer);

        $user->changeEmail('foo@bar.com');
        $this->assertCount(1, $observer->getChangedUsers());
    }
}
```

When I tried to run this test, I got the following error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /home/.../.../Test/ObserverTest.php on line 9
```

I installed PHPUnit with composer, here is my composer.json file content:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"DesignPatterns\\": "src/"}
    }
}
```

According to [PHPUnit 6 documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies), your tests are now supposed to extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase instead of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.

I know it's not an issue with autoloading. Actually, if I replace PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase with PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase, it works just fine, but I was wondering why this syntax didn't works.

I tried some research on google, stackoverflow and PHPUnit's github repository, but couldn't find anything.

I am looking forward for your answers,

**EDIT**

This is how my files are organized:

```
src/
├── DataMapper
│   ├── StorageAdapter.php
│   ├── UserMapper.php
│   └── User.php
├── Observer
│   ├── UserObserver.php
│   └── User.php
Test/
├── DataMapperTest.php
└── ObserverTest.php
```

Comment: go in vendor and look if phpunit is there or not

Comment: the test file is in the src folder? if yes it should have the DesignPatterns suffix in the namespace?

Comment: Hi, yes, phpunit is there.

Comment: no, the test file is not in src/, it's in a Test folder

Comment: how do you load the test folder in the autoloader?

Comment: no need to load the test folder in the autoloader. I created phpunit.xml file to match the Test directory

Comment: You can also use the answer from the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811164/class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found/42828632#42828632 to keep your code compatible with PHPUnit 6 as well as earlier versions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer:

I was excuting my test with this command line:

```
phpunit Test/ObserverTest.php
```

PHPUnit is installed globally on my computer, but it's the 5.1.3 version:

```
phpunit -v

PHPUnit 5.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 with Xdebug 2.4.0
Configuration: /home/.../.../DesignPatterns/phpunit.xml
```

And the syntax PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase only works with PHPUnit 6

Now, if I run `php vendor/bin/phpunit Test/ObserverTest.php`, it works perfectly...

Comment: Just to confirm, you only updated the version of phpunit to v5.1.3?

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this in case somebody ends up here after upgrading to Symfony 4.4 / 5.0 and is having this error.

In newer versions of Symfony, you have a version which is defined in the `phpunit.xml.dist`. This version will be downloaded when you run `./bin/phpunit` and it's sources will be placed under `./bin/.phpunit/phpunit-VERSION`. If you are executing `php ./bin/console --env=test debug:container` you might get the mentioned by the OP exception. The fix is easy - you need to add the path to the classes in the `composer.json`:

```
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "tests/",
            "bin/.phpunit/phpunit-9.2.0-0/src" <--- Make sure the version is correct.
        ]
    },
```

Afterwards run `composer dump-autoload` and finally `php ./bin/console --env=test debug:container` should work.

Comment: I ended up with this: `"autoload-dev": { "psr-4": { "App\\Tests\\": "tests/" }, "classmap": [ "bin/.phpunit/phpunit/src" ] },`. `bin/.phpunit` is a symlink. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a different version of phpunit earlier in my path in the /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin directory.  After creating a symbolic link to the globally installed version (7.5.1) instead of 5.1.3, this fixed the error for me:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
mv phpunit phpunit_bak
ln -s /usr/local/bin/phpunit phpunit
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are facing `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` not found in PhpStorm,

run `php bin/phpunit` at root of project, it will download all needed classes and PhpStorm error should gone

Comment: `php bin/phpunit` gives to me phpunit info and manual