# Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found

Tags: travis-ci

This error occurs on my public build project: https://travis-ci.org/byjg/authuser/jobs/211336643

I ran locally using php 7.0 and php 7.1 on my Ubuntu and this problem does not occur.

Travis runs successful on PHP 5.6

Could you help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a difference between namespace structure between `PHPUnit` <6 and `PHPUnit` 6.

You may consider the following solution for backward compatibility:

```
// backward compatibility
if (!class_exists('\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase') &&
    class_exists('\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase')) {
    class_alias('\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase', '\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase');
}
```

The old `PHPUnit` versions use `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` but the new one uses `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`. With the backward compatibility applied you can use the class name that is compatible with the new version of `PHPUnit` (i.e. `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`) and it is going to work also with older versions.

**Update**
In order to cover support for PHP 5.3 you have to remove a `\` character before the alias class, i.e.

```
class_alias('\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase', 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase');
```

Comment: You saved my day :)

Comment: Works great for PHP 5.4 - 7.1 but does not seem to work with PHP 5.3

Comment: @chris342423 I've updated my answer. There is a note about PHP 5.3.

Comment: I've updated my test script and yep, I can confirm that your idea works. Thanks for the update!