# Travis cannot find 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' – sometimes

Tags: php, continuous-integration

I've just started using [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) to test my PHP code. [Sometimes](https://travis-ci.org/ms609/citation-bot/builds/274572281), builds fail with the message

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /home/travis/build/ms609/citation-bot/tests/phpunit/expandFnsTest.php on line 13`

On [other occasions](https://travis-ci.org/ms609/citation-bot/builds/274573081), without my having changed any relevant code, the builds succeed.
This makes me suspect that the issue is at Travis's end rather than my own.

This makes me wonder: is there anything that I can do to reduce the likelihood of my encountering this error?  And on builds when the error arises, is it possible to have Travis re-attempt the build without making a new commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class 'PHPUnit\_Framework\_TestCase' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811164/class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found)

Comment: I've clarified the answer below to make it clear why the answer there did not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had inherited a testcase written using an older version of phpunit.  For backwards compatibility, following [advice elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811164/class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found), I had added the code

```
if (!class_exists('\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase') &&
    class_exists('\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase')) {
    class_alias('\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase', 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase');
}
```

What I needed to do next was replace

```
class myTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
```

with

```
class myTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
```

With regards to the second part of the question, signing in to Travis CI reveals a "restart build" option on the build page.